# How do you make General Tso's chicken as generally found in the Eastern USA?

Tags: chicken, restaurant-mimicry

I realize this is a recipe request, but I'm hoping that the supplemental information will be enough to let it through. I also realize it's rather localized and apologize to all of those who don't know what I'm on about.

So, I am a *huge* fan of [General Tso's chicken](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Tso's_chicken). I grew up on the east coast of the USA in the DC/VA area. Every dish of General Tso's was more or less the same: breaded deep fried chicken, a spicy, thick, reddish brown sauce with a hint of sweetness, chili peppers, sesame seed, and  broccoli.

Since moving to Chicago I have been unable to find this style of General Tso's. Out here the sauce is runny, brown, sickly sweet, and barely spicy. They also put all kinds of random crap (vegetables) that I don't want in there. I've tried this dish in L.A., Seattle, and Phoenix and it's all similarly gross. I've even had one where the chicken wasn't breaded!

The dish I want to know how to make looks like this:

[image: General Tso's Chicken]

I realize D.C./VA is a rather specific area, but since this dish originated in New York City, I *imagine* that it didn't get butchered much migrating 200 miles south. So, while I haven't had NYC General Tso's I imagine that it's quite similar, or at least much closer than the mess I have out here in the midwest.

**Update**

I'd prefer first-hand knowledge to a top 3 Google hit.

Comment: I usually went for other dishes, but the times I had General Tso's growing up in the Detroit metro area sounds like what you described.  So you may have to go only a few hours east :). http://www.urbanspoon.com/r/19/233742/restaurant/Detroit/Kim-Toa-Warren

Comment: Not exactly convenient. :P

Comment: @hobodave: closer than VA/DC/NY

Comment: In Montreal area, this is called General Tao chicken and it is the way you describe it from the DC/VA area.

Comment: There's a little strip-mall chinese joint near here that makes a nearly perfect General Tso's chicken. Flavorful, spicy, crunchy. I order it at least 75% of the time. I would love to have a great recipe of this dish also.

Comment: @Tim: Ask for their recipe and share? :D

Comment: hobodave, if this question (  http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/1241/whats-a-good-recipe-for-us-style-teriyaki-chicken-closed)

was closed, then I'm going to have to vote to close your question as well:

Comment: I think you might be able to get away with it if you posted a recipe you have tried, and pointed out the flaws in it, then you might be able to solicit suggestions for modifications.  But in its current form it seems too localized (only a few places in North America) and too subjective (the only real answer correct answer depends on your taste buds).  as well as being borderline off topic.  So apart from not being an exact duplicate, being about the site and actually being a question, you have hit all of the reasons to close :-).  Good work ;-).

Comment: @Sam: I'd just like to point out a few significant differences between the two posts. I don't pose it as a "what is a good", nor "what is the best" question. I've listed most of the ingredients in it. My region isn't a "few places", as stated by myself and indicated by commenters it covers nearly the entire eastern seaboard of North America, as far inland as Michigan. I'd hardly call that _too localized_, as opposed to an interstate exit in a single city. However, it's your vote to do with as you please.

Comment: @Sam: I suggest you read http://meta.cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/49/restaurant-mimicry-questions-allowed and voice your opinions there, or start a new meta if you don't feel this quite fits into that mold.

Comment: @hobodave, maybe as a non american part of a country seems a small area to me.  Agreed that it is not a 'what is a good' or 'what is best', but I still feel that it would be better phrased as a 'how can I fix this so it is more like X', and would have a wider audience even if they had never eaten the actual dish in question.  Also part of me feels that as you are highly reputable, it may be seen as favouritism for 'the in crowd' and maybe that is clouding my judgement

Comment: @Sam: When talking about regional food, `too localized` is a bit of a farce, as I'm sure most people would agree.  There are sweets found only in West Bengal.  Does that mean discussion about Bengali sweets is not allowed here because they are `too localized`? what about szechuan food?  As a cooking Q&A site, I would expect it to be slightly more open to such questions.

Comment: PS.  West Bengal is 1/25th the size of New York State, and Vietnam is about the size of the East Coast.  Henceforth, I suggest we vote to close Vietnamese and Bengali cuisine questions as too localized...

Comment: @Sam: I disagree with you in this case because the OP (hobodave) has provided objective criteria for evaluating the answers.  Specifically, there are criteria for the colour, spiciness, and basic ingredients.  I am intimately aware of the differences between what dave is referring to and the generic "General Tso" you find on recipe sites and many restaurants.  This is a difficult question with an objectively correct answer, whereas "U.S. Style Teriyaki Chicken" can actually refer to any number of different dishes, and the only criteria given was "damn good."

Comment: @Aaronut, @Sam, and @hobodave... shouldn't this discussion be happening in meta? That way it's preserved for posterity and not just in the comments of a question? We should want to be able to point to it when similar situations arise in the future.

Comment: @Aaronut, @Sam, and @hobodave, here is the relevant discussion that happened on meta: http://meta.cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/49/restaurant-mimicry-questions-allowed/70#70 From the criteria listed there, this question looks like it's on topic.

Comment: @Mike: You are correct. I tried to steer it there earlier.

Comment: @hoboodave, I see your link to it there now buried in this wall of comments. My mistake :-)

Comment: I started a new thread on meta for the discussion of this as I didn't feel that the existing one linked to already quite fits the bill.  http://meta.cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/376/what-defines-too-localized

Comment: @hobodave: omg, why did you have to include the pic??? This is one of my favorite guilty pleasures ever and now I can't stop thinking about it.

Comment: OMG. This guy is so right. The General Tso's chicken elsewhere is not quite the same as in the metro DC area. The sauce is sweet, spicy and red tinged. Not brown. (Chen's on Macaurther Blvd comes to mind!) If anyone has a GOOD general tso's chicken that isn't full of Hoisin sauce, I would love to have it...
Lots of recipes on here, but none of them taste like the restaurant. Thanks

Comment: The image included doesn't work. Firefox says it cannot be displayed as it includes errors. I tried rehosting it to SE's standard image host, and it refused, saying that it was not a valid image file.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Many restaurants actually serve a "light" version of the Tso sauce, and I have a pretty strong feeling that's what you're used to.

To make the light version, you use 3x the corn starch and add 1/2 cup of the base liquid (usually chicken broth).

The hint of sesame almost certainly came from toasted sesame oil, my favourite "secret ingredient" that goes into just about every Asian stir-fry.

To get a more consistent flavour for the sauce, instead of using "minced" garlic, you might want to grate it using a fine rasp, if you have one.  This will definitely help to bring out the flavour of the garlic and subsequently the spiciness of the sauce.

Grated orange zest is another common additive, and although it's *traditionally* labeled as a different recipe ("General Tso's Chicken with Orange"), some restaurants sneak it into the regular recipe.  If you remember any hint of orange, try adding about 1 tsp of this.

Finally, if we're trying to recreate a recipe from an American Chinese restaurant, it's very likely they used some MSG.  You can leave it out, but we all know how much of a flavour enhancer it is.

I don't actually have an *exact* recipe kicking around, but adapting these changes to the "traditional" recipe, it should look something like this:

- 1 cup chicken broth
- 1/4 cup soy sauce
- 2-3 tbsp rice wine or sherry (to taste)
- 1 tsp toasted sesame oil
- 1/4 cup sugar
- 1 tsp MSG (optional)
- 1 1/2 tbsp rice vinegar
- 3 tbsp tapioca flour or corn starch
- 6-10 dried red chilies
- 1 tbsp minced ginger
- 1 tbsp grated or finely minced garlic

I'm going to skip the ingredients and preparation for the fried chicken itself, since that's pretty straightforward and no different from any of the "normal" Tso recipes.  So let's assume that part has already been done.  Here's how I'd make the sauce and finish it off:

- Combine the chicken broth, soy sauce, rice wine, sesame oil, sugar, [MSG], and rice vinegar.  Make sure that the sugar is completely dissolved.
- Add tapioca to the soy sauce mix and dissolve.
- Heat a few tbsp of oil in your wok and start frying up the chilies.  The longer you fry them, the hotter the final dish will be, so adjust the timing to taste.  Many restaurants skimp here, and either don't use enough chilies or don't fry for anywhere near long enough.  You're looking for a deep, dark red, *almost* black colour for optimum heat.
- Add the soy sauce / tapioca mix, garlic and ginger, and stir.
- Once thickened, add the chicken and serve with the broccoli.  (You most likely got it steamed, that's how it looks in the picture, although my choice would be to stir-fry it with some red pepper flakes.)

I can't promise you that this will be identical to what you got in the restaurants, as I haven't been to those restaurants, but hopefully this sounds a lot closer to what you had than the garbage you traditionally find in lower-end restaurants and on recipe sites.

---

**Update:** After reading some of the results of this experiment, I would add the following (better late than never, right?):

- The above ratio of starch to water will result in a very thick, almost paste-like consistency.  That's intentional, but if you want something more "saucy", i.e. to put on rice, then don't triple the starch, especially if you're using tapioca.  2 tbsp should be sufficient.  At the same time, keep in mind that it's always easier to dilute a sauce that's too thick than it is to thicken it in the wok once it's already hot.
- If you're finding that it's still not spicy enough (I, too, like my spicy dishes *blazing* hot), then try including any or all of the following in the sauce:

  - 1 tsp chili oil
  - 1 tsp hot chili sauce (proper chili sauce like sriracha, not tabasco)
  - 2-3 fresh red chilies, cut into rings, with seeds (caution: *very* hot)

Comment: I'm going shopping this afternoon. I'm going to try this tonight, I'll let you know how it turns out.

Comment: @hobodave: Looking forward to hearing about it!  Hope I didn't make any major screwups in my adjustments, it's always easier when I'm in the kitchen. ;)

Comment: @Aaronut: Operation Tso is complete. Photos: http://www.flickr.com/photos/hobodave/sets/72157624450024941/ It certainly looks like what I'm used to, and the orange zest is definitely a nice touch. However, it just wasn't that spicy (hot). I had to redo the peppers because the first batch burnt so quickly, it took maybe 2 minutes to fry the peppers before they would burn. Also, the consistency of this was SUPER THICK. It went from liquid to paste in a flash, I had to add another cup of broth to get it somewhat normal. It's still somewhat _off_ in consistency, it oozes off in sheets.

Comment: It certainly tastes good, and it's better than the crap I've had out here in Chicago. I think it just needs more heat, and a consistency tweak. Eating the chilis gives it a nice kick of heat though.

Comment: @hobodave: Interesting, how many chilies did you use?  And did you use tapioca or corn starch?  Generally there's no other "heat source" in General Tso, but if you're not getting the right amount of heat, you might consider chili oil, or an actual fresh chili pepper (with seeds).  In any case, I'm glad to hear that it was at least a moderate success; if you get it really nailed down in the future after a few iterations, be sure to give us an update!

Comment: @Aaronut: I used a big handful, like 20. I used tapioca, my first time. Do you think I overcooked the sauce? It literally went from broth like consistency to super snot in less than 5 seconds.

Comment: Also @hobodave, that's actually roughly the consistency I thought you were going for, since you complained about runniness; should've been more specific!  (Edit: No, you probably didn't overcook, but a ratio of 3 tbsp to 1 cup *will* form almost a paste; the original recipe uses 1 tbsp to 3/4 cup and is runny; to get the consistency you want right now, I guess you'd want to use about 2 tbsp.  And my guess is that since you had to dilute it, that's part of why it turned out a bit less spicy.)

Comment: It's hard to describe consistency in words.

Comment: Oh, and I have to ask... did you use MSG?  Even though I never do, it tends to affect your perception of heat, and that could be why it tasted spicier in the restaurants... the other thing you could do is use chili sauce, like the sriracha hot sauce.

Comment: So @hobodave, those photos are from tonight?  They actually look pretty damn close, aside from not being able to see any actual chilies.  (And the broccoli is a little less vibrant - but that might be just lighting.)

Comment: @Aaronut: Yes I used MSG. I have a much more heat tolerant palate than most, so I think I'll do what you suggest and take matters into my own hands next time. The photos are from tonight. There are actually 4 chilis in the first picture (some look like a shadow) and 1 in the closeup. And it does actually look very close to what I'm used to, maybe slightly less red. Do you think they use cayenne in the sauce for heat and color? And yea, I overcooked the broccoli for a few minutes when I got distracted.

Comment: @hobodave: I'd be very surprised if they used cayenne.  Chili sauce is more likely - some tend to be quite red in colour.  I also wouldn't rule out artificial colouring - or even natural colouring, from something like turmeric.  I'm admittedly guessing, though; the only way to know for *sure* would be to ask them...

Comment: @hobodave About the consistency issue: The chef of my favorite DC-area restaurant uses lotus flour as a coating for his marinated chicken before frying it and then adding the chicken to his sauce. It might be worth it to you to experiment with lotus flour because the General Tso's I enjoyed last night tastes exactly like the dish you describe.

Comment: @Iuls: I've never heard of that! I'll definitely try to get some this weekend and try it.

Comment: @Aaronut: G-Tso 2.0 was attempted last night. I made the following changes from your original recipe: (1) Breaded with Tapioca flour instead of Cornstarch. (2) Added 1/2 tsp of seeds that were in the bottom of the dried red chili bag. (3) Forgot to buy an orange. (4) Used 2 Tbsp of tapioca flour in sauce. (5) Used 1 tsp of "chili infused toasted sesame oil" (best I could find at the store I was at, I didn't feel like making a second stop).

Comment: @Aaronut: Analysis: Breading the chicken with the tapioca flour was _weird_. The cooked flour became suspended in the oil as I progressed which subsequently clung to the cooked chicken as well as clogged my strainer. Cornstarch didn't do this, the debris sunk to the bottom. I'm going to try lotus flour as @Iuls suggested next time. The seeds added a nice bit of heat, I sauteed them briefly (5s) as the chilis were darkening. They cook fast. The orange zest was noticeably lacking. The sauce consistency was much better with the reduced tapioca. The appearance is still weird though...

Comment: @Aaronut: ... the sauce wasn't too think or too thin, but it did form "sheets". Think this is the tapioca? The chili infused sesame oil didn't really bring much heat that i could tell. I could taste no heat in the uncooked sauce. I think I'm going to have to get pure chili oil or try the sriracha you suggested. I think I'll try G-Tso 3.0 this weekend.

Comment: @hobodave, you are truly committed to this one!  I definitely would not have recommended using tapioca as a breading, but I guess you found that out for yourself.  I'm not totally sure what you mean by "sheets", and I don't think I've ever seen chili-infused sesame oil (though it sounds interesting).  Really best to separate the hot ingredients from the sweet/savoury ingredients as much as possible, because otherwise you can't really control the heat.  If you're after mega heat, I'd still suggest that you consider a few fresh chilies; with seeds intact, they heat up like nobody's business.

Comment: @hobodave: Also, although it's never been my experience, some people on here insist that acid intensifies heat, so you could try adding a little lime or lemon juice - just a few squeezes.

Comment: Lastly, @hobodave, back to consistency: It's possible that tapioca isn't exactly right for the way you personally want this - it's more potent than corn starch and tends to form a more jelly-like consistency, which is what *I'm* used to but maybe not what *you've* had - if you think that might be the culprit, my suggestion would be to split the sauce into two halves, and try corn starch in one half and tapioca in the other.  Starch is the last ingredient anyway, so it should be easy to split this way.

Comment: @Aaronut: The interesting part re: the tapioca batter was it tasted much better than cornstarch. The plain chicken fried in cornstarch tasted like.. fried cornstarch. The chicken fried in tapioca tasted _good_; there were just the technical challenges. It might have gone better if there were room for me to fry all of it at once, but I had to do it in a few batches due to my pot size and the temperature drop.

Comment: This recipe is very close to the one I use.  The one thing that I would mention is that almost all the Chinese restaurants in the new york area use dark meat for the general tso chicken.  Now that I live in the middle of nowhere and have to make my own Chinese food, I found that that detail made a surprising amount of difference.

Answer (score 3):

Originally from the Northeast US, I too was surprised that one of my favorite Chinese take-away dishes was so radically different. The 2 critical bits for me was recreating the texture of the "breading" and the sauce.  I found that, for me, baking or sauteing the chicken first, then "breading" with a corn starch or tapioca batter WITHOUT LEAVENING and frying in oil gave the best results for the chicken.  Too many places use some kind of leavening so instead of a crispy shell (akin to a KFC drumstick) instead I found I was eating a puffy dough ball.

The second bit, to make the sauce closer to my expectations. Aaronut has a good response there.  Adding a healthy measure of garlic and getting the sugars to carmelize and reduce to a sticky brown almost-but-not-quite glaze... yumm!

Comment: BTW, the tapioca batter was not pleasant to fry with.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if [this](http://chinesefood.about.com/od/poultryreceo/r/generaltso.htm) is the right recipe, as I have only had General Tso's chicken by this recipe and in a small town in upstate NY, but it tasted good to me.

Answer (score 0):

[here is a recipe](http://chinesefood.about.com/od/poultryreceo/r/generaltso.htm). really your worry will be the sauce itself. cornstarch is the secret to the  thickening part. if you are new to cooking i would suggest just working on a sauce first and play with the elements first. every chinese place does it differently. the chicken is simple to cook so get the sauce and your good to go